# RegEx extract string, keep lines intact

Tags: regex, extract

I’d like to extract a specific set of string out of a text file with some thousand lines. The file has empty lines which are crucial to be kept. I manage to match all strings, but I do not manage to keep them while deleting everything else that might be in them in the same line. I’ve tried negative lookaheads – they only manage to match one instance of the pattern per line.

I was using SublimeText but I could use any command line regex interpreter as well.

My data looks like this:

```
....
Some Text, more text
[empty line]
Silberdruck
Golddruck, Silberdruck
[empty line]
Some Text, Silberdruck
Golddruck some text, Silberdruck
...
```

I need to keep all words containg *druck, so the data should look like this:

```
....    
[empty line]
[empty line]
Silberdruck
Golddruck, Silberdruck
[empty line]
Silberdruck
Golddruck Silberdruck
....
```

The pattern might appear multiple times per line.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `(\h*\w*druck\b[[:punct:]\h]*)|.` -> `$1` in Sublime

Comment: Thanks, this works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(\h*\w*druck\b[[:punct:]\h]*)|.
```

And replace with `$1`

*Details*:

- `(\h*\w*druck\b[[:punct:]\h]*)`  - Group 1 capturing the sequence of

  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `druck\b` - `druck` followed with a word boundary
  - `[[:punct:]\h]*` - zero or more punctuation or horizontal whitespace
- `|` - or
- `.` - any char other than a line break char